# Gzip works only after refresh (content-encoding)

Tags: php, iis, gzip, iis-6

I set up my server (IIS 6) to compress my really big json. However, when I launch my app, the file is downloaded without gzip
[image]

If I refresh, the file is well gzipped with the header **Content-Encoding**.[image]

The file is generated with PHP. At the top of my PHP file, I put

```
if (!in_array('ob_gzhandler', ob_list_handlers())) {
        ob_start('ob_gzhandler');
    } else {
        ob_start();
    }
    set_time_limit(0);
    header('Content-Encoding: gzip');
```

And I'm creating my file with `file_put_contents('data.json', $res);`

`no-cache` is needed as I'm refreshing the file every 20 minutes. Do you have a solution to enable `gzip` on the first launch? I don't want to tell my clients they need to refresh..